# Do you need vaccinations for a stopover in Australia?

Tags: paperwork, australia, health, stopovers

I need to stop over in Australia, to go to and come back from New Zealand.

Given that I don't need any visa for the stopovers, I wonder if I should get some specific vaccination, or bring any certificate of it. I did all the compulsory vaccinations here in Europe, but the little book certifying it is in my home country.

How does it work in Australia? Will I be asked for these certificates? And when? (When boarding? At check-in time? When landing over?)

Is it common to be checked about it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are no requirements for any vaccinations when travelling to or transiting through Australia, with the exception of Yellow Fever vaccination if you come from an affected area.

There are some vaccinations which may be recommended if you travel in some remote areas, but I guess the won't be the case if you are just doing a short stopover in one of the major hubs.

You can find more information on the US CDC site:

https://wwwnc.cdc.gov/travel/destinations/traveler/none/australia

(US-centric, but a good source anyway).

If you tell us which country you are from, where you will be stopping and for how long, there would be some additional information.

Comment: Yes, I read about Yellow Fever as the only requirement, but was not sure if it is a mandatory for **every** traveller or just in some specific case. 
I'm from Italy, but living in Germany (and departing from there). The stopover in Australia will be 2 hours long (coming from London, Singapore and New Zealand). Am not going to go out from the airport but just re-check my luggage in for the following flights.

Comment: @Kamafeather See [Australia's Yellow Fever requirements](http://www.health.gov.au/internet/main/publishing.nsf/Content/health-pubhlth-strateg-communic-factsheets-yellow.htm#09). The vaccination doesn't seem to be strictly mandatory—"People unable to provide a certificate will still be able to enter Australia"—and only applies to those traveling to/from [Yellow Fever risk countries](http://www.health.gov.au/internet/main/publishing.nsf/Content/health-pubhlth-strateg-communic-factsheets-yellow.htm#07). Germany, the UK, Singapore, and New Zealand are not countries with Yellow Fever.

Comment: Definitely no need for vaccination in your case, and they won't ask for anything in that respect in your case. Note that since you are staying only a couple of hours, this is actually a **layover** rather than a **stopover** (which is usually defined as over 24 hours). Do you really need to re-check luggage? If you do need to go through passport control (twice), baggage claim, customs, check-in and security, 2 hours can quickly become very very short if there are any delays, especially if you factor in the baggage drop deadline. You'll also need an ETA.